# Json decode function not decoding in PHP

Tags: php, sql, ajax, postgresql, postgis

I'm calling some polygon features from my postgreSQL database, using the PostGIS extension. 
When I run the two queries below in pgAdmin. It returns 2 features. And the attribute table only contains the geom field and no more attributes.

```
 //query 1
$sql = $db->query(
           "CREATE TABLE table_union AS
            SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(geom,0.0001)) as geom
            FROM areas_demo
            GROUP BY type;"
         );
//query 2
$sql = $db->query(
           "SELECT * FROM table_union ;"
         );
```

So, I run the following PHP code through an AJAX call.

```
//compiling result to create a geoJSON file
          $features=[];
          while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $feature=['type'=>'Feature'];
            $feature['geometry']=json_decode($row['geom']);
            unset($row['geom']);
            $feature['properties']=$row;
            array_push($features, $feature);

          }
          $featureCollection=['type'=>'FeatureCollection', 'features'=>$features];
          echo json_encode($featureCollection);
```

It runs perfectly, but the response I get in the ajax success function is:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":
[
    {"type":"Feature","geometry":null,"properties":[]},
    {"type":"Feature","geometry":null,"properties":[]}
]}
```

It miss the geometry column.

When I comment the line:

```
//unset($row['geom']);
```

and use the following one instead:

```
$feature['geom'] = json_decode($row['geom']);
```

I receive in the following result:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":
[
    {"type":"Feature","geometry":null,"geom":null,"properties":{"geom":"0106000020E6100000030000000103000000010000000C000000304CA60A4...."}},
    {"type":"Feature","geometry":null,"geom":null,"properties":{"geom":"0106000020E6100000030000000103000000010000000800000048E17A14A...."}}
]}
```

In other words, the json_decode function is not working in the way I was expecting. Someone has a hint why?

What I was expecting is the following geoJSON format to be read by Leaflet:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -9.1353, 38.7089 ], [ -9.1327, 38.7085 ], [ -9.1329, 38.7075 ], [ -9.1339, 38.7066 ], [ -9.1349, 38.7065 ], [ -9.1369, 38.7066 ], [ -9.1395, 38.7062 ], [ -9.1409, 38.7065 ], [ -9.141, 38.7071 ], [ -9.1395, 38.708 ], [ -9.1376, 38.7088 ], [ -9.1353, 38.7089 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.1353, 38.7148 ], [ -9.1358, 38.713 ], [ -9.131, 38.7131 ], [ -9.1313, 38.7148 ], [ -9.1334, 38.7159 ], [ -9.1353, 38.7148 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.1373, 38.7117 ], [ -9.1373, 38.711 ], [ -9.1382, 38.711 ], [ -9.1389, 38.7117 ], [ -9.138602739726027, 38.712167123287671 ], [ -9.1388, 38.7122 ], [ -9.1391, 38.7125 ], [ -9.139, 38.7131 ], [ -9.1386, 38.7137 ], [ -9.1375, 38.7138 ], [ -9.1368, 38.713 ], [ -9.1365, 38.7116 ], [ -9.1373, 38.7117 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -9.14, 38.7137 ], [ -9.1401, 38.7146 ], [ -9.1393, 38.7146 ], [ -9.1384, 38.714 ], [ -9.1385, 38.7129 ], [ -9.1393, 38.7125 ], [ -9.1403, 38.7127 ], [ -9.14, 38.7137 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.142254171066526, 38.709864202745514 ], [ -9.1429, 38.7096 ], [ -9.1437, 38.7105 ], [ -9.142446368715083, 38.71144022346369 ], [ -9.1426, 38.7127 ], [ -9.1395, 38.7103 ], [ -9.1421, 38.7086 ], [ -9.142254171066526, 38.709864202745514 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.1352, 38.7093 ], [ -9.135114856230031, 38.709287539936099 ], [ -9.1354, 38.7102 ], [ -9.134548387096778, 38.710412903225809 ], [ -9.136, 38.7108 ], [ -9.1332, 38.7128 ], [ -9.1322, 38.7126 ], [ -9.1327, 38.7115 ], [ -9.1334, 38.7107 ], [ -9.1328, 38.7102 ], [ -9.1323, 38.709 ], [ -9.132510550458722, 38.708906422018352 ], [ -9.1311, 38.7087 ], [ -9.132, 38.7074 ], [ -9.1337, 38.7075 ], [ -9.1346, 38.7084 ], [ -9.134733333333335, 38.7086 ], [ -9.1349, 38.7086 ], [ -9.135047058823528, 38.709070588235292 ], [ -9.1352, 38.7093 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

Image of what I get when I execute the code on db
[image]

Comment: `411363CBD5A4340C05B2041F14322C0A69BC420B05A4340DD4637804422C0C3F528` does not look like json!

Comment: Can you please add an example of what you get when you execute this directly on the db?

Comment: `null` is returned when `json_decode` encounters an error. So probably `$row['geom']` is not valid json

Comment: What is the expected output? As far as I know, geometry data is stored in binary format, not a human readable format.

Comment: if you want to array result you should pass second parameter in json_decode function Something like json_decode(json_string, true)

Comment: @GeoMaps please describe what kind of out put you want

Comment: @GeoMaps . . . Do not use `union` as a table name.  It is a SQL key word.

Comment: It was not using it was used as an example

Comment: Print the output of `json_decode($sampleRowGeom)`. I'm pretty sure you're trying to decode something that is not json which leads to the function returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the output of `json_decode($sampleRowGeom)` and you'll realize why this happens.

From the `json_decode()` manual:

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

The value you're fetching from that union table isn't valid json.

Comment: OMG, you're totally right, I need to convert the geom field to geoJSON in order to work using the followiong code: ST_AsGeoJSON(geom, 5) AS geojson.